# Order by minimum values per group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to order by PODID then CYID but sometimes a t.ID will have multiple PODIDs and/or CYIDs. All rows with the same t.ID should be together.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.ID AS TariffID,
    t.TradeID,
    pod.PODID,
    cy.CYID
FROM 
    TB_Import_Tariff_Tier t (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    TB_Import_Tariff_Tier_POD_Group_History pod (NOLOCK) ON t.ID = pod.ID 
INNER JOIN 
    TB_Import_Tariff_Tier_CY_Group_History cy (NOLOCK) ON t.ID = cy.TariffID
ORDER BY 
    pod.PODID, cy.CYID
```

Expected result:

```
TariffID TradeID PODID  CYID
------------------------------
185       18       1    17939
185       18       1    17941
246       18       1    17939
246       18       1    17941
266       18       1    17939
266       18       1    17941
280       18       1    17939
280       18       1    17941
285       18       1    17939
252       18       1    17945
```

Edit: Sample was too small, here is the full result with Order By t.ID, pod.PODID, cy.CYID

```
+----------+---------+-------+-------+
| TariffID | TradeID | PODID | CYID  |
+----------+---------+-------+-------+
|      251 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      252 |      18 |     1 | 17945 |
|      254 |      18 |     4 | 17939 |
|      254 |      18 |     4 | 17941 |
|      255 |      18 |     4 | 17936 |
|      256 |      18 |     8 | 18091 |
|      257 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      261 |      18 |     4 | 17939 |
|      261 |      18 |     4 | 17941 |
|      262 |      18 |     8 | 17936 |
|      263 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      266 |      18 |     1 | 17939 |
|      266 |      18 |     1 | 17941 |
|      267 |      18 |     4 | 17936 |
|      268 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      271 |      18 |     8 | 17939 |
|      271 |      18 |     8 | 17941 |
|      272 |      18 |     1 | 17936 |
|      273 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      274 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      274 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      275 |      18 |     4 | 17939 |
|      275 |      18 |     4 | 17941 |
|      276 |      18 |     8 | 17936 |
|      277 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      279 |      18 |     1 | 18091 |
|      279 |      18 |     1 | 18093 |
|      280 |      18 |     1 | 17939 |
|      280 |      18 |     1 | 17941 |
|      281 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      284 |      18 |     8 | 18093 |
|      285 |      18 |     1 | 17939 |
|      286 |      18 |     1 | 18091 |
|      287 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      290 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      290 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      291 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      292 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      293 |      18 |     4 | 17947 |
|      294 |      18 |     4 | 17945 |
|      295 |      18 |     8 | 17939 |
|      295 |      18 |     8 | 17941 |
|      296 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      296 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      297 |      18 |     1 | 17936 |
|      300 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      301 |      18 |     4 | 17936 |
|      302 |      18 |     8 | 18091 |
|      303 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      306 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      306 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      307 |      18 |     4 | 17936 |
|      308 |      18 |     8 | 18093 |
|      310 |      18 |     8 | 18093 |
|      311 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      312 |      18 |     4 | 17939 |
|      312 |      18 |     4 | 17941 |
|      313 |      18 |     4 | 17936 |
|      316 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      316 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      317 |      18 |     1 | 17936 |
|      318 |      18 |     1 | 18091 |
+----------+---------+-------+-------+
```

All the PODID = 1 should be together first but if there's another PODID for the same t.ID they should be together.

If t.ID is at the end of the Order by it's still incorrect because the IDs are not together

```
+----------+---------+-------+-------+
| TariffID | TradeID | PODID | CYID  |
+----------+---------+-------+-------+
|      272 |      18 |     1 | 17936 |
|      297 |      18 |     1 | 17936 |
|      317 |      18 |     1 | 17936 |
|      266 |      18 |     1 | 17939 |
|      280 |      18 |     1 | 17939 |
|      285 |      18 |     1 | 17939 |
|      266 |      18 |     1 | 17941 |
|      280 |      18 |     1 | 17941 |
|      252 |      18 |     1 | 17945 |
|      279 |      18 |     1 | 18091 |
|      286 |      18 |     1 | 18091 |
|      318 |      18 |     1 | 18091 |
|      279 |      18 |     1 | 18093 |
|      255 |      18 |     4 | 17936 |
|      267 |      18 |     4 | 17936 |
|      301 |      18 |     4 | 17936 |
|      307 |      18 |     4 | 17936 |
|      313 |      18 |     4 | 17936 |
|      254 |      18 |     4 | 17939 |
|      261 |      18 |     4 | 17939 |
|      275 |      18 |     4 | 17939 |
|      312 |      18 |     4 | 17939 |
|      254 |      18 |     4 | 17941 |
|      261 |      18 |     4 | 17941 |
|      275 |      18 |     4 | 17941 |
|      312 |      18 |     4 | 17941 |
|      294 |      18 |     4 | 17945 |
|      293 |      18 |     4 | 17947 |
|      251 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      274 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      277 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      290 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      291 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      296 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      306 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      316 |      18 |     4 | 18091 |
|      257 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      263 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      268 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      273 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      274 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      281 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      287 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      290 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      292 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      296 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      300 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      303 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      306 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      311 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      316 |      18 |     4 | 18093 |
|      262 |      18 |     8 | 17936 |
|      276 |      18 |     8 | 17936 |
|      271 |      18 |     8 | 17939 |
|      295 |      18 |     8 | 17939 |
|      271 |      18 |     8 | 17941 |
|      295 |      18 |     8 | 17941 |
|      256 |      18 |     8 | 18091 |
|      302 |      18 |     8 | 18091 |
|      284 |      18 |     8 | 18093 |
|      308 |      18 |     8 | 18093 |
|      310 |      18 |     8 | 18093 |
+----------+---------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: See [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Adding the DDL and sample data in a usable form, e.g. as table variable declarations and `insert` statements, makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on displaying the results. I've fixed it.

For the NOLOCK, this is not my decision to make. I know there are better ways to prevent build up but my team lead wants us to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to order the data like this:

```
ORDER BY
    MIN(PODID) OVER (PARTITION BY TariffID),
    MIN(CYID) OVER (PARTITION BY TariffID),
    TariffID,
    PODID,
    CYID
```

This will put TariffID groups with smallest PODID and CYID first, then sort within each TariffID by individual PODID, CYID:

```
| TariffID | TradeID | PODID | CYID  |
|----------|---------|-------|-------|
| 272      | 18      | 1     | 17936 |
| 266      | 18      | 1     | 17939 |
| 266      | 18      | 1     | 17941 |
| 252      | 18      | 1     | 17945 |
| 255      | 18      | 4     | 17936 |
| 267      | 18      | 4     | 17936 |
| 254      | 18      | 4     | 17939 |
| 254      | 18      | 4     | 17941 |
| 261      | 18      | 4     | 17939 |
| 261      | 18      | 4     | 17941 |
| 275      | 18      | 4     | 17939 |
| 275      | 18      | 4     | 17941 |
| 251      | 18      | 4     | 18091 |
| 274      | 18      | 4     | 18091 |
| 274      | 18      | 4     | 18093 |
| 257      | 18      | 4     | 18093 |
| 263      | 18      | 4     | 18093 |
| 268      | 18      | 4     | 18093 |
| 273      | 18      | 4     | 18093 |
| 262      | 18      | 8     | 17936 |
| 271      | 18      | 8     | 17939 |
| 271      | 18      | 8     | 17941 |
| 256      | 18      | 8     | 18091 |
```

[DB Fiddle for Short](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5cc994919e3cd89a9a1e0d0c53a2a757) and [Long Data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8debb003e79b571d1342ee022c336913)

Comment: Yes this is it, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `t.ID` in the `ORDER BY` clause. Did you try this? Or am I seeing this differently?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.ID AS TariffID,
    t.TradeID,
    pod.PODID,
    cy.CYID
FROM 
    TB_Import_Tariff_Tier t (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    TB_Import_Tariff_Tier_POD_Group_History pod (NOLOCK) ON t.ID = pod.ID 
INNER JOIN 
    TB_Import_Tariff_Tier_CY_Group_History cy (NOLOCK) ON t.ID = cy.TariffID
ORDER BY 
    t.ID,pod.PODID, cy.CYID
```

Comment: That doesn't make `252       18       1    17945` the last row as requested.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it looks like that making `T.ID` the last element in the `Order By` clause would do what the OP requested.